# Missing jar file error

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, compilation

I am developing an application with many functionality, where one functionality requires a jar file which is only commercially available. When I release it for public use for free, I have to remove this jar file from my source. When I run this application in Eclipse IDE with the jar file removed, it gives me "Errors exist in required Project". I would like to avoid this warning.

1. Only the users using the library should be able to access its corresponding functionality (The application has many functionality.)
2. Users who don't include this jar file should be able to access other functionality without any error/warning.

Requirement:

1. Gray out the functionality based on the absence of the jar file.
2. Avoid the warning message when I run the Main.java

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need indeed is dynamic class loading, isn't it?
To enable this feature, you have some options:

1. Implement your own classloader.
2. Use [OSGI](http://www.osgi.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Additional to yanana's solution, you can simply leave the commercial JAR file in your Eclipse project. When creating your setup you can create one setup for commercial use (including the JAR) and one for the open source version (without the JAR).

But you should be carefully separate the usage of the commercial classes into one or more package/module. At runtime you can check the presence of one class which is part of the commerical JAR file via reflection before accessing code dependent on the commercial JAR.

Your integration tests should contain some corresponding test cases with and without the commercial JAR in classpath.